# Firebug kind of editor for jsp?

Tags: firebug

Is there a firebug kind of editor for jsp in eclipse, which formats the jsp in a tree structure, so that developer gets a better view of jsp elements?

Answer (score 0):

Well when working with web elements/components i've found that Aptana Studio (the Eclipse plugin) can be very helpful.

http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download